# How do I grant gcp org policy permissions at the folder or project level?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a service account that I want to use to set org policy constraints on specific projects, and all of those projects are under a common folder. The specific constraint is constraints/compute.restrictSharedVpcSubnetworks so I can control which subnets each project has access to in the shared vpc.

To be able to set a constraint, the service account needs the roles/orgpolicy.policyAdmin role.

The documentation seems to indicate I can only grant this on the org itself, and not below at either the folder or project level. I have tried granting it on a folder and I get an error.

I don't want to give my service account that much permission, I want to really restrict it to the folder or even the project level if possible.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: No. Some permissions are granted at the Org level.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation [Organization Policy roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#organization-policy-roles):

[image: organization_policy_roles]

As you can see, for `roles/orgpolicy.policyAdmin` lowest resource is organization.
Some roles could be used only at organization level as it was suggested by *@John Hanley*.

There's no quick way to change it, but you can file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) at [Google Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) under [this component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187161&template=1162660).